# AmCharts removing columns from dataProvider with validateData() not working

Tags: javascript, html, charts, amcharts

I recently asked about a [way to hide columns in AmCharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46328387/hiding-columns-with-amcharts-possible-via-legend) using hide/show buttons, and it worked pretty well. However, I am now separating functions into different files to create a more dynamic web application.

The page *peptide.html* holds mostly HTML code, and refers to *displayAmCharts.js* for the displaying of the AmChart and to any file, in this case *1A80_HUMAN_R_QDAYDGK_D.js*, in the data/peptide folder to dynamically load data from. Loading and displaying the data in the AmChart is working fine, however when trying to emplement the hide/show function I get into errors with AmChart.

Every time the function hideValue() is called, a new dataProvider is generated and the old gets replaced the results in the AmChart are just **BLANK**. Try it yourself in this [JS Bin example](https://jsbin.com/megitayule/edit?html,output), show some of the data, select a column to hide, click hide and you'll see that the outlining of the chart stays almost the same, the legend still shows the same selection but there is actual data being displayed.

The strange thing is there commentary code in displayAmCharts() works to replace the values, but when these aren't hard-coded the replacement doesn't work. Some logs to the control of what exactly additionalData contained showed nothing out of the ordinary, i.e. the same structure of data as in the default dataProvider.

**Any clues on why the data isn't being shown correctly?**

Code below can also be found on JS Bin:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
  </head>   
<script>
  // Source would be C:/Users/Username/Documents/Visualisation Tool/data/peptide/1A80_HUMAN_R_QDAYDGK_D.js
  var graphValues = [{
    "balloonText": "Control: [[value]]",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "id": "Control",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lineColor": "#008000",
    "title": "Control",
    "type": "column",
    "newStack": true,
    "valueField": "Control",
    "hidden": true},
{
    "balloonText": "Control SD: [[value]]",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "id": "Control SD",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lineColor": "#000000",
    "title": "Control SD",
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "Control SD",
    "hidden": true},
{
    "balloonText": "Sample A: [[value]]",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "id": "Sample A",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lineColor": "#008080",
    "title": "Sample A",
    "type": "column",
    "newStack": true,
    "valueField": "Sample A",
    "hidden": true},
{
    "balloonText": "Sample A SD: [[value]]",
    "fillAlphas": 1,
    "id": "Sample A SD",
    "lineAlpha": 1,
    "lineColor": "#000000",
    "title": "Sample A SD",
    "type": "column",
    "valueField": "Sample A SD",
    "hidden": true},
{
    "title": "All",
    "id": "all",
    "legendValueText": "",
    "legendPeriodValueText": "",
    "hidden": true
}];
var dataValues = [{
    "glycan": "Hex5HexNAc4NeuAc1",
    "Control": 100.0,
    "Control SD": 10.0,
    "Sample A": 80.0,
    "Sample A SD": 8.0},
    {
    "glycan": "Hex5HexNAc4NeuAc2",
    "Control": 50.0,
    "Control SD": 10.0,
    "Sample A": 4.0,
    "Sample A SD": 4.0}
    ];
</script>
  <script>
    // Source would be C:/Users/Username/Documents/Visualisation Tool/scripts/displayAmCharts.js
    var hiddenValues = [];
    var dataProviderVals;

    function displayAmCharts(additionalData){
      var graphsVals = graphValues;
      dataProviderVals = dataValues;
      var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
        "type": "serial",
        "dataProvider": dataProviderVals,
        "legend": {
          "useGraphSettings": true,
          "borderAlpha": 1,
          "align": "center",
          "spacing":  125,
          "listeners": [ {
            "event": "hideItem",
            "method": legendHandler
          }, {
            "event": "showItem",
            "method": legendHandler
          }]
        },
        "categoryField": "glycan",
        "categoryAxis": {
          "autoWrap": true
        },
        "rotate": false,
        "graphs": graphsVals,
        "valueAxes": [
          {
            "stackType": "regular",
            "id": "ValueAxis-1",
            "position": "left",
            "axisAlpha": 1
          }
        ],
        "export": {
          "enabled": true
        }
      });   

      /*
      This manual code below works to replace the data.

      var test = [{
        "glycan": "Hex5HexNAc4NeuAc3",
        "Control": 100.0,
        "Control SD": 10.0,
        "Sample A": 80.0,
        "Sample A SD": 8.0},
        {
        "glycan": "Hex5HexNAc4NeuAc4",
        "Control": 50.0,
        "Control SD": 10.0,
        "Sample A": 4.0,
        "Sample A SD": 4.0}
        ];
      chart.dataProvider = test;
      chart.validateData();
      */

      if(additionalData != undefined){
        // Replace the dataProvider with additionalData from hideValue and redraw the chart.
        chart.dataProvider = additionalData;
        chart.validateData();
      }
      function legendHandler(evt) {
        var state = evt.dataItem.hidden;
        if (evt.dataItem.id == "all") {
          for (var i1 in evt.chart.graphs) {
            if (evt.chart.graphs[ i1 ].id != "all") {
              evt.chart[evt.dataItem.hidden ? "hideGraph" : "showGraph" ]( evt.chart.graphs[ i1 ]);
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    function hideValue(){
      var selection = document.getElementById("selection");
      var selectedValue = selection.options[selection.selectedIndex].value;
      hiddenValues.push(selectedValue);
      var newDataProvider = [];
      dataValues.forEach(function(item){
        if(hiddenValues.includes(item.glycan) == false){
          newDataProvider.push(item);
        }
      });
      displayAmCharts(newDataProvider);
    }

    function fillSelection(){
      var select = document.getElementById("selection");
      var options = [];
      dataProviderVals.forEach(function(item){
        options.push(item.glycan);
      });
      for(var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        var opt = options[i];
        var el = document.createElement("option");
        el.textContent = opt;
        el.value = opt;
        select.appendChild(el);
      } 
    }
  </script>

    <body onload="displayAmCharts(); fillSelection()">
        <header>
            <h1><b>Visualisation Tool<b></h1>
        </header>
        <h2></h2>
        <div id="chartdiv"><p>Unfortunately there is no data available.</p></div>

        <div>
            <select class="select" id="selection">
                <option disabled selected>Select an option.</option>
            </select>
            <button class="button" type="button" onclick="hideValue()">Hide</button>
            <button class="button" type="button">Show</button>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Commentary in this version as all JS scripts are included in the same page.
        // Open .JS file that contains data at C > Users > User > Documents > Tool folder > Data > Peptide > peptide based on value stored in localStorage, example would be localStorage.getItem("peptideSelection") = "1A80_HUMAN_R_QDAYDGK_D".
        // var peptide = localStorage.getItem("peptideSelection");
        // var JSLink = "C://Users//Z678187//Documents//StackExample//data//peptide//"+peptide+".js";
        // C://Users/Z678187//Documents/StackExample//data//peptide//1A80_HUMAN_R_QDAYDGK_D.js would be the file location.
        // var JSElement = document.createElement('script');
        // JSElement.src = JSLink;
        // JSElement.onload = OnceLoaded;
        // document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(JSElement);
        // function OnceLoaded() {
        //  displayAmCharts();
        //  fillSelection();
        // }
    </script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably has to do with recreating the chart every time `displayAmCharts` is called. It is unneccessary and will get amCharts confused. I would define `chart` as a global variable and only create the chart once.

**Your globals**

```
var hiddenValues = [];
var dataProviderVals;
var chart = null; // chart as global variable
```

**displayAmCharts function**

```
function displayAmCharts(additionalData){

  var graphsVals = graphValues;
  dataProviderVals = dataValues;

  // create chart only once
  if(chart == null){

    chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
      "type": "serial",
      "dataProvider": dataProviderVals,
      // ...
    });

  }

  if(additionalData != undefined){
    // Replace the dataProvider with additionalData from hideValue and redraw the chart.
    chart.dataProvider = additionalData;
    chart.validateData();
  }

  // ...

}
```

That should solve the issue :-)

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick, I also replaced the calling of displayAmCharts from the hideValue function and immediately changed the dataProvider by

`chart.dataProvider = newDataProvider`